# Surface plotting using a CSV file

Tags: matlab, csv, gnuplot

I use a csv file containing all surface data, the storing format is as following:

[image]

The data  can be easily plotted by matlab routine surf（）：

[image]

Now I need to plot the data using gnuplot. I've tried pm3d script. But the result was not good. Can any one help me with this? Any ideas will be appreciate!

Comment: splot "data1.txt" matrix nonuniform with pm3d t ''

Answer (score 0):

```
splot "data.csv" nonuniform matrix u 1:2:3 w pm3d,\
```

"line.csv" u 1:2:3 w l lc 1 lw 3

Everything is as expected when using this snip of code with gp507. But the same code would produce quirk results if running with higher version of gnuplot. So I think it's something with gnuplot, not my script.

Comment: I can get an expected result with 507 and other older versions of gnuplot